# 100vh Not Tall Enough On Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, height, viewport-units

So, I'm trying to make a mobile version on my desktop site (Have a look here to see what I'm going for www.adamaucock.com).

The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to set the height correctly, in that my content is about half the page and then the rest is just dead space so the height is set too short for the window. Working with the body tag didn't work and I've seen people suggesting wrapper elements also but I can't seem to get that to work. I've tried using vh and %. I've also tried hiding the overflow for x and y separately and together on both elements to no avail.

The only thing that fixed the issue was setting the wrapper to be fixed but then the scrolling didn't work at all.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box" id="welcome_box">
        <div class="welcome_title">
            <h2 id="video_head">Hi, I'm Adam.</h2>
            <h1>And here I am testing this website.</h1>
            <h3>Scroll to See More</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #04244F;
    font-family: raleway;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}

#wrapper {
    width: 500vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

`overflow-y: hidden` on the body/html should do the trick

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #04244F;
            font-family: raleway;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 500vw;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
        h2 {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="box" id="welcome_box">
            <div class="welcome_title">
                <h2 id="video_head">Hi, I'm Adam.</h2>
                <h1>And here I am testing this website.</h1>
                <h3>Scroll to See More</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hadn't tried that. Just tested it and it didn't seem to change anything I'm afraid.

Comment: What are you using to test?

Comment: As in what device? Using a gen 1 Google Pixel and an iPhone 4 that I had from ages ago. Both have the same issue.

Comment: Do you need vertical scrolling at all?

Comment: No, ideally I'd cut out vertical scrolling all together.

Comment: Updated answer with a working sample. Tested on Pixel 2.

Answer (score -1):

So, I have just found a solution but I'm not sure how well it'll work across devices. I used the viewport meta tag to set the initial scale  to .25 rather than 1 like so.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.25">
```

On the two devices I have to hand (Google Pixel 1 and iPhone 4) it seems to work. Will update if I run into any problems with this approach.